# Linphone linphone_core_iterate crash

Tags: ios, swift, timer, linphone

I'm using [Linphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybo2S.png) lib, and I'm facing a crash on line `linphone_core_iterate` while loop, after destroying core (`linphone_core_unref`).
Here is my code

```
func prepareToShutdown() {
    iterateTimer = nil
    iterateTimer?.invalidate()

    shutdown()
}

func shutdown(){
    NSLog("Shutdown..")

    let proxy_cfg = linphone_core_get_default_proxy_config(lc); /* get default proxy config*/
    linphone_proxy_config_edit(proxy_cfg); /*start editing proxy configuration*/
    linphone_proxy_config_enable_register(proxy_cfg, 0); /*de-activate registration for this proxy config*/
    linphone_proxy_config_done(proxy_cfg); /*initiate REGISTER with expire = 0*/

    linphone_core_unref(lc);
}

@objc func iterate(){
    if let lc = lc {
        print("iterating")
        linphone_core_iterate(lc); /* first iterate initiates registration */
    }
}

func setTimer(){
    iterateTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(
        timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(iterate), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

And here is crash screenshot [image]

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I got an solution for this issue. I was using a Intel NUC (even different versions) and it always crashed at this point with System.AccessViolationException.

For Windows the solution is to alter the Thread.Sleep(20) sleep time due to CPU overload and this causing a deadlock.